# Fill SQLAlchemy ORM with custom query

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, orm, sqlalchemy

For my python application, am I using SQLAlchemy (with Flask) with an MySQL database.
I have my tables as ORM in my code.

However, my database is designed as a version controlled database, where instead of updating the rows, a new row gets added with a date of change.

For example
**Tables**

> **Section**
>
> - Upload_id (pk, fk)
> - id (pk, fk)
> - name
> - deleted (default: False)
>
> **Upload**
>
> - id (pk)
> - upload *(The datetime)*

---

**The question** 
I want my ORM to load the objects and all relations, but load for each ID the latest version (if not deleted, than load no version at all).
I made this in a Query, however I did not manage to recreate this in a Query object, nor have I any clue where to call it to 'overwrite' the normal load Query.

```
SELECT og.* FROM section og JOIN (
SELECT uu.id as u_id, i.id as s_id FROM upload uu JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(u.upload) as maxu, s.id FROM vc_section s
        JOIN upload u ON s.upload_id = u.id
        GROUP BY s.id
    ) i ON uu.upload = i.maxu
) sss ON og.id = sss.s_id AND og.upload_id = sss.u_id
```

Comment: Do you really have 2 tables named `vc_section` and `section`, or is that a typo?

Comment: It's a typo, they are both called vc_section

Comment: To "overwrite" a normal query, if I've understood you correctly, you could use [`aliased`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased). Pass your query as the [`alias`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased.params.alias) argument, so that the ORM class is mapped against the query. Something along the lines of `LatestSection = aliased(Section, your_query_here)` and then use the new mapping as usual: `Session.query(LatestSection)...`.