# AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute '_query_cls'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, sqlalchemy-utils

`User.id` was of type `postgresql.UUID`
`Message.sender_id` was of type `postgresql.UUID` with foreignkey to `User.id`.

Changed my type to `sqlalchemy_util.UUIDType`.

I had a problem for serializing my foreign key so I set my own `JSONEncoder`
Now everything is working properly except when creating a `Message` (other classes with the same configuration does not have the problem).

**test_message.py**

```py
def test_create_message(client, db, admin_user, admin_headers):
    # test bad data
    data = {
        'message': 'foobar',
        'title': 'title',
    }
    rep = client.post(
        '/api/v1/messages',
        json=data,
        headers=admin_headers
    )
    assert rep.status_code == 422

    data['sender'] = admin_user.id.hex
    data['recipient'] = admin_user.id.hex

    rep = client.post(
        '/api/v1/messages',
        json=data,
        headers=admin_headers
    )
    assert rep.status_code == 201

    data = rep.get_json()
    message = db.session.query(Message).filter_by(id=data['message']['id']).first()

    assert message.message == 'foobar'
    assert message.title == 'title'
```

**models/message.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils import UUIDType

from supervisor.extensions import db

from .notification import Notification


class Message(Notification):
    """Basic message model
    """
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    __repr_attrs__ = ['sender', 'message']
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('notification.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        primary_key=True
    )
    sender_id = db.Column(
        UUIDType(binary=False),
        db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
    )
    sender = db.relationship(
        'User',
        lazy='joined',
    )
    message = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('type', 'message')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

**models/user.py**

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    """Basic user model
    """
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __repr_attrs__ = ['email']
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    photo_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    company_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('company.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        nullable=False
    )
    admin_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('company.id'),
        nullable=True
    )
    sites = db.relationship(
        'Site',
        secondary='users_sites',
        lazy='joined',
    )
    tel_office = db.Column(db.String(25))
    title = db.Column(db.String(128))
    supplies = db.relationship(
        'Supply',
        lazy='joined',
        backref='contact'
    )
    notifications = db.relationship(
        'Notification',
        lazy='joined',
        backref='recipient',
        foreign_keys='[Notification.recipient_id]',
        cascade='all,delete-orphan',
        passive_deletes=True,
    )
```

**models/base.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy_mixins import AllFeaturesMixin, ReprMixin

from supervisor.extensions import db


class BaseModel(db.Model, AllFeaturesMixin, ReprMixin):
    __abstract__ = True
    __repr__ = ReprMixin.__repr__

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

**output of the test suite**

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_create_message _______________________________________________________________________________________________

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'supervisor'>>, db = <SQLAlchemy engine=postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:***@/rework-product-test?host=/cloudsql/flowlity:europe-west1:supervisor-db-test>
admin_user = <User #a7b838c3a8e64d118b13b1b28ab41f5f 'admin@flowlity....'>
admin_headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1Njc0Mzg0MDgsIm5iZiI6MTU2NzQzODQwOCwianRpIjo...yZXNoIjpmYWxzZSwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.Zd5pOLAR5YSHDugU52E4qN-xQmXoqyJZTR_LNEbsUYM', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

    def test_create_message(client, db, admin_user, admin_headers):
        # test bad data
        data = {
            'message': 'foobar',
            'title': 'title',
        }
        rep = client.post(
            '/api/v1/messages',
            json=data,
            headers=admin_headers
        )
        assert rep.status_code == 422

        data['sender'] = admin_user.id.hex
        data['recipient'] = admin_user.id.hex

        rep = client.post(
            '/api/v1/messages',
            json=data,
>           headers=admin_headers
        )

tests/test_message.py:35: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1039: in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/testing.py:227: in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects,
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:993: in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:884: in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1119: in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:2463: in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py:46: in __call__
    start_response)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py:74: in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:2449: in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py:269: in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py:161: in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1866: in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:38: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446: in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py:269: in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py:161: in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820: in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:38: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935: in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py:458: in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py:89: in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py:573: in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py:103: in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
supervisor/api/resources/message.py:51: in post
    message = schema.load(request.json)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py:216: in load
    return super(ModelSchema, self).load(data, *args, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py:684: in load
    data, many=many, partial=partial, unknown=unknown, postprocess=True
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py:799: in _do_load
    unknown=unknown,
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py:639: in _deserialize
    index=index,
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py:483: in _call_and_store
    value = getter_func(data)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py:632: in <lambda>
    val, field_name, data, **d_kwargs
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py:329: in deserialize
    output = self._deserialize(value, attr, data, **kwargs)
.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/fields.py:109: in _deserialize
    self.session.query(self.related_model), value
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <class 'supervisor.models.user.User'>, entities = (), kwargs = {}

    def query(self, *entities, **kwargs):
        """Return a new :class:`.Query` object corresponding to this
        :class:`.Session`."""

>       return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
E       AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute '_query_cls'

.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:1544: AttributeError
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{'message': 'foobar', 'title': 'title'}
{'message': 'foobar', 'recipient': 'a7b838c3a8e64d118b13b1b28ab41f5f', 'sender': 'a7b838c3a8e64d118b13b1b28ab41f5f', 'title': 'title'}
```

Comment: Your `User` model doesn’t have an attribute called _query_cls, can you include it’s definition in the question please?

Comment: @SuperShoot I added my User class

Comment: And what is the definition of `BaseModel`?

Comment: I added my Base class. sqlalchemy_mixins was for CRUD but I had bugs with save/delete so I implemented my own

Comment: OK I think I'm getting close, do you create a marshmallow-sqlalchemy `ModelSchema` object somewhere in your code and pass it a sqlalchemy session?

Comment: Yes, every model has its own api endpoint and objects are managed by a ModelSchema intiated by the model and sqla_session, do you want the source code of the ModelSchema for Message/User ?

Comment: OK. It looks like you are passing in _the_ `Session` class to your schema instances instead of a `Session()` instance. The reason I say this is that the method that the error originates from is `Session.query`, but the `self` in the context of that function is your `User` class. So when sqlalchemy-marshmallow does this: `self.session.query(self.related_model)`, `self.related_user` which is your `User` class is getting passed to the self parameter of the `Session.query` method. If `ModelSchema.session` was a `Session()` instance, `self` would be that instance. Hope I've explained that OK.

Comment: Omg those typo... I was passing db.Session instead of db.session...

Answer (score 0):

As said by SuperShoot,

My ModelSchema was wrongly instanciate:

```py
class MessageSchema(ma.ModelSchema):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        sqla_session = db.Session
```

The answer was to correct

```py
        sqla_session = db.Session
```

to

```py
        sqla_session = db.session
```